# Seeing form data with a Node.js script

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms

I want to see the data entered in a form in a html file run from a local folder. In a book from which I am learning from, it doesn't give detailed instructions, but it says I should run a js file with Node, with the following code:

```
var http = require('http');
var querystring = require('querystring');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
 switch(req.url) {
 case '/form':
 if (req.method == 'POST') {
 console.log("[200] " + req.method + " to " + req.url);
 var fullBody = '';
 req.on('data', function(chunk) {
 fullBody += chunk.toString();
 });
 req.on('end', function() {
 res.writeHead(200, "OK", {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
 res.write('<html><head><title>Post data</title></head><body>');
 res.write('<style>th, td {text-align:left; padding:5px; color:black}\n');
 res.write('th {background-color:grey; color:white; min-width:10em}\n');
 res.write('td {background-color:lightgrey}\n');
 res.write('caption {font-weight:bold}</style>');
 res.write('<table border="1"><caption>Form Data</caption>');
 res.write('<tr><th>Name</th><th>Value</th>');
 var dBody = querystring.parse(fullBody);
 for (var prop in dBody) {
 res.write("<tr><td>" + prop + "</td><td>" + dBody[prop] + "</td></tr>");
 }
 res.write('</table></body></html>');
 res.end();
 });
 } else {
 console.log("[405] " + req.method + " to " + req.url);
 res.writeHead(405, "Method not supported", {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
 res.end('<html><head><title>405 - Method not supported</title></head><body>' +
 '<h1>Method not supported.</h1></body></html>');
 }
 break;
 default:
 res.writeHead(404, "Not found", {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
 res.end('<html><head><title>404 - Not found</title></head><body>' +
 '<h1>Not found.</h1></body></html>');
 console.log("[404] " + req.method + " to " + req.url);
 };
}).listen(8080);
```

Then, when I enter the data and click the submit button, I should be redirected to page with the data entered inside a table. The page url should end with :8080/form.

What exactly should I do here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The instructions seem simple enough. What, specifically don't you understand?

Comment: How do I link the script with the html?

Comment: "The page url should end with :8080/form" — That's the URL you put in the forms action.